# How to add multilingual support to a custom WordPress theme built with ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Maybe I'm missing something here, but I really can't find any answer to my question around the web.

I'm working to add multilingual support to the text of a custom WordPress theme. The website, for the most part, has been developed off of ACF fields; & I'm unsure as to how to access the `.po` files associated with these text fields.

I've followed some steps outlined in a previous [Stack Exchange question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248462/how-to-develop-a-multilingual-theme?answertab=active#tab-top), (about a similar matter) using Poedit to translate the default WordPress text from the `theme.pot` file, however this does not include the text input via the ACF plugin.

Additionally, I already have all the translated text for the website, so we would like to avoid licensing any 3rd party software/development tools, such as automatic translation plugins.

Answer (score 2):

There are some plugins, most of them are not free and I had problems with the others.

How many languages do you want to support?

Most of the time I clone the website to a subdomain en.example.com and translate it there or install wordpress as a multisite.

Regards Tom